# Length scale between matplotllib figure size and xelatex doesn't match

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, xelatex, pgf

I created a python `matplotlib` figure with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xwidth = 418.25555 / 72 # conversion from in to pt
ywidth = 300 / 72 # conversion from in to pt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[xwidth, ywidth])
ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
ax.set_ylabel("Y-label")
ax.set_xlabel("X-label")
fig.savefig("test.pgf", bbox_inches="tight", pad=0)
```

I determined the `xwidth` via `\the\textwidth` in XeLaTeX and have to convert it to inches. One inch is defined as 72 pt. However, if I include the graphic into my document, it doesn't match the linewidth:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \input{test.pgf}
  \end{figure}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam\newline
  Linewidth: \the\textwidth
\end{document}
```

Here is the result:
[image: Example of not matching graphic width]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In TeX, a pt is 1/72.27 in. However, that only accounts for about half a millimeter in this case, so there must be something else as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, when you use `bbox_inches="tight"`, you shorten the figure to remove the white space, and do not extend the axes.

Using `constrained_layout = true` or `plt.tight_layout()` works under latex for me.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xwidth = 418.25555 / 72 # conversion from in to pt
ywidth = 300 / 72 # conversion from in to pt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[xwidth, ywidth], constrained_layout = True)
ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
ax.set_ylabel("Y-label")
ax.set_xlabel("X-label")
fig.savefig("test.pdf")
```

or

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xwidth = 418.25555 / 72 # conversion from in to pt
ywidth = 300 / 72 # conversion from in to pt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[xwidth, ywidth])
ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
ax.set_ylabel("Y-label")
ax.set_xlabel("X-label")
plt.tight_layout()
fig.savefig("test.pdf")
```